# How do I remove an entity or element from the scene in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I am building a component that watches (in `tick`) the position of its entity, and when some condition is met, it removes the entity from the scene. How can I do the removing part?

For example:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('remove-on-tick', {
  tick: function () {
    if (condition) {
      // Remove entity.
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Removing an entity is the same as in DOM:

```js
entityEl.parentNode.removeChild(entityEl);
```

If you have a sphere:

```
var sphere = document.querySelector('a-sphere');
sphere.parentNode.removeChild(sphere);
```

In a component, we have a reference to the entity via `this.el`:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('remove-on-tick', {
  tick: function () {
    var entity = this.el;
    if (condition) {
      entity.parentNode.removeChild(entity);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Does it have to go through the parentNode?

Comment: yeah, it's the standard javascript/DOM API